# Wifi stops working on Macbook Pro (Lion)

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, wifi, internet

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Internet stops working frequently on OS X Lion](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/18383/internet-stops-working-frequently-on-os-x-lion)

Just bought Macbook pro 2011 running on Lion. I connect to my WiFi, but it has started happening frequently that internet stops working even though my DSL modem and wifi router are ON and working perfectly, as I acess it via my phone also. But on mac, no internet. To fix it either I need to restart the machine or turn wifi OFF and then ON.

Is this issue common on OS Lion?

any solutions?

Thanks

Comment: I believe this has been fixed by the latest updates. Also, repeat question - this is/was a common issue with Lion.

Comment: How to update it?